# What's the reason for the 42 layer limit in Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, storage, unionfs, docker-overlay2

At different places I found the information that a docker image can only consist of up to 42 layers. This seems to be a limitation of the used AUFS file system.

Can anybody tell me why this limit exists or does anybody have some documentation explaining this?

Comment: 42 is the answer for everything.

Comment: @levi: that I know and thanks for the fish ;-)

Answer (score 8):

I'm starting to suspect that there isn't any such a hard limit.

Create the following python script, and name it "makeDockerfile.py"

```
with open("Dockerfile", "w") as file:
    file.write("from alpine:3.8\n")
    for i in range(0, 201):
        file.write("run echo {i}\n".format(i=i))
```

then run
`python makeDockerfile.py && docker build --tag manylayer . && docker run -it manylayer /bin/sh`
You'll see that you are running a working container with > 200 layers.

(note, this was tested with linux containers on linux)

Note that this doesn't mean that this many layers are necessarily SUPPORTED, just that they are possible in some cases.

In fact, I've seen containers fail with far fewer than 42 layers, and removing any arbitrary layer seems to fix it. (see https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/676#issuecomment-462991673 )

**EDIT**:

`thaJeztah`, maintainer of Docker, has this to say about it:

> The "42 layer limit" on aufs was on older versions of aufs, but should no longer be the case.
>
> However, the 127 layer limit is still there. This is due to a restriction of Linux not accepting more than X arguments to a syscall that's used.
>
> Although this limit can be raised in modern kernels, it's not the default, so if we'd go beyond that maximum, an Image built on one machine may not be usable on another machine.

( see https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/8230 )

Comment: I suppose that this today is no problem anymore, keep in mind that this question is over 2 years old. At that time this was a hardcoded limit based on the AUFS filesystem which was used as default by docker. If you now run `docker info` and check for the storage, it will be probably different that aufs;

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be imposed primarily by [AUFS](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/) ([`sfjro/aufs4-linux`](https://github.com/sfjro/aufs4-linux)).
See [PR 50 "Prohibit more than 42 layers in the core "](https://github.com/shykes/docker/pull/50)

> > Hey, out of curiosity, what's the detailed rationale behind this?
> > People have been asking how to bypass the 42 layers limit, and we've always told them "wait for device mapper!" so... what should we tell them now?

> We can't allow more than 42 layers just yet. Devicemapper indeed supports it, but then, if you push a 50 layer image to the registry, most people won't be able to use it. We'll enable this once we support more than 42 layers for AUFS.

[PR 66](https://github.com/shykes/docker/pull/66) was supposed to remove that limit

[This thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6801560) reported:

> The 42 limit comes from the aufs code itself.
> My guess is that it's because of stack depth: if you stack these kernel data structures too many levels deep, you might trigger an overflow somewhere. The hard-coded limit is probably a pragmatic way to avoid that.

---

With Docker v1.12 (Q3 2016), that limit was raised to 128, [commit 23e5c94](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/23e5c94cfb26eb72c097892712d3dbaa93ee9bc0)

> ### Add separate overlay2 driver
>
> Adds a new overlay driver which uses multiple lower directories to create the union fs.
> Additionally, it uses symlinks and relative mount paths to allow a depth of 128 and stay within the mount page size limit.
>
> Diffs and done directly over a single directory allowing diffs to be done efficiently and without the need fo the naive diff driver.

Comment: 42 seems quite popular in that aufs codebase: https://github.com/sfjro/aufs4-linux/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=42+max+&type=Code

Comment: Their lucky number?:) The null hypothesis can be probably rejected against the surrounding numbers differing by just 1, but not if they are rounded to full 10s (40 and 50 are way more popular:)

Answer (score 2):

From the [Docker BP documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/):

> #### Minimize the number of layers
>
> You need to find the balance between readability (and thus long-term maintainability) of the `Dockerfile` and minimizing the number of layers it uses. Be strategic and cautious about the number of layers you use.

They also give advices on how to avoid too many layers:

> That way you can delete the files you no longer need after they’ve been extracted and you won’t have to add another layer in your image
>
> [..]
>
> Lastly, to reduce layers and complexity, avoid switching USER back and forth frequently.

---

**TL;DR:** the benefit of minimizing the number of layers can be likened to the benefit of minimizing the number of small files but rather have fewer bigger ones. A `docker pull` is also faster (*try downloading 2048 files of 1kB or one file of 2MB*) . and having fewer layers reduces the complexity of an image, hence the maintainability.

As for the `42` limit. Well... I guess they had to come up with a number and they pick this particular one ;)

Answer (score 1):

The current limit on the number of Docker image layers (including all nested images) is **128** (not 42 which was probably valid at the moment when the question was asked) and it results from the limitation of the current default / preferred storage driver `overlay2`, as justified in Docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/):

> The overlay2 driver natively supports up to 128 lower OverlayFS layers. This capability provides better performance for layer-related Docker commands such as docker build and docker commit, and consumes fewer inodes on the backing filesystem.

Comment: Good update. Upvoted.

Comment: The update is valid, and yes the 42 was the limit when I asked and is it not anymore. But my question was not why is there a limit, but why it was set to this special value. So please don't change my original posts title to a different meaning.