# Should I minimize the number of docker layers?

Tags: docker, optimization, dockerfile, layer

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/) doesn't elaborate on the topic a lot. It says:

> Minimize the number of layers
>
> Prior to Docker 17.05, and even more, prior to
> Docker 1.10, it was important to minimize the number of layers in your
> image. The following improvements have mitigated this need:
>
> In Docker 1.10 and higher, only RUN, COPY, and ADD instructions create
> layers. Other instructions create temporary intermediate images, and
> no longer directly increase the size of the build.
>
> Docker 17.05 and higher add support for multi-stage builds, which
> allow you to copy only the artifacts you need into the final image.
> This allows you to include tools and debug information in your
> intermediate build stages without increasing the size of the final
> image.

It looks like the latest Docker versions don't solve the problem of handling many layers. They rather strive to reduce their number in the final image. Most importantly, the docs don't tell **why** many layers are bad.

I'm aware of the [AUFS limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39383801/2116625) of 42 layers. It makes sense to keep the number of layers small for widely used images because it helps other images built on top of them fit the restriction. However, there are another storage drivers and images for other purposes.

It is also good to keep images small for an obvious reason - they take up disk space and network bandwidth. However, I don't think that [chaining RUN statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223249/multiple-run-vs-single-chained-run-in-dockerfile-what-is-better) and thus squashing many layers into one helps in general. In case different RUNs update different parts of the filesystem one layer and many layers together should be approximately the same in size.

On the other hand, many layers allow to make use of cache and rebuild images faster. They are also pulled in parallel.

I work in a small team with a private Docker registry. We won't ever meet the 42 layers restriction and care mostly about performance and development speed.

If so, should I minimize the number of docker layers?

Comment: "Efficient images are ultimately a tradeoff of size balanced against what you need to reliably and easily support your application." https://blog.codeship.com/reduce-docker-image-size/

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help a lot. There are many ways to keep layers lightweight. Sometimes cleaning a layer up makes a huge difference and makes a lot of sense. But IMHO it has nothing to do with the number of layers.

Comment: What I meant is that there is not a correct answer for what you are asking. You have to study what is better for your case. If you are a small team with a little infrastructure, maybe you don't even need to worry about that.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> I work in a small team with a private Docker registry. We won't ever meet the 42 layers restriction and care mostly about performance and development speed.

If so, should I minimize the number of docker layers?

In your case, no.
What needs to be minimized is the build time, which means:

- making sure the most general steps, and the longest are first, that will then cached, allowing you to fiddle with the last lines of your Dockerfile (the most specific commands) while having a quick rebuild time.
- making sure the longest RUN command come first and in their own layer (again to be cached), instead of being chained with other RUN commands: if one of those fail, the long command will have to be re-executed. If that long command is isolated in its own (Dockerfile line)/layer, it will be cached.

---

That being said, [the documentation you mention](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/) comes from [`docker/docker.github.io`](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io), precisely [PR 4992](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/pull/4992) and [PR 4854](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/pull/4854), after a [`docker build LABEL` section](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label).
So this section comes after a similar remark about `LABEL`, and just emphasize the commands creating layers.
Again, in your case, that would not be important.

Comment: I get your point about putting long-running command in its own line (layer) for caching purpose, but not sure if it's important to put that line first before other trivial commands. Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: You have to put the long-running commands first because if you change the trivial commands this will cause the long-running commands also to be rerun.
This is because the cache is not correct anymore.

Answer (score 48):

I just wanted to see what were the differences of 2 images, one built with multiple RUNs and the other built with one RUN concatenating commands.

In the first case, the images are doing trivial operations (creating and deleting files).

Content of the "single" layer image:

```
FROM busybox

RUN echo This is the 1 > 1 \
    && rm -f 1 \
    && echo This is the 2 > 2 \
    && rm -f 2 \
# ... for about 70 commands
```

Content of the multiple layers image:

```
FROM busybox

RUN echo This is the 1 > 1
RUN rm -f 1
RUN echo This is the 2 > 2
RUN rm -f 2
# ... for about 70 layers
```

The build time is very different (multiple: 0m34,973s, singular: 0m0,568s). The container start-up time is also different but less noticeable (multiple: 0m0,435s, singular: 0m0,378s). I've run different times the images but the times do not change that much.

Concerning the space, I've looked on purpose for the worst case for the multiple layer case and as expected the multiple layer image is bigger than the single layer.

In another test, I concatenated layers that only add content to the image. The build time does not change from the previous case but the run-time case shows something a little different: the multi layer image is faster to start-up than the single layer image. Concerning the space, same results.

I don't think this proves anything but I had fun in doing it :P

Comment: Very edge case when layers are so trivial that layer-enabling structures probably occupy more space (and time) than actual useful payload of the layer. It would be better if you illustrated with a real life examples.

Answer (score 46):

Reducing the number of layers is less of a goal itself. Rather what you need to focus on is reducing build time and also reducing image size.

Build time is reduced by keeping common layers that rarely change at the top of your Dockerfile, or in a base image. This allows the layer to be cached and reused in later builds. This is less about reducing the number of layers, and more about ordering your layers well.

Reducing image size helps reduce the disk usage on registry servers, which see a large hit to the disk when images are stored for each build on a CI system. It also reduces the network time to transfer the image. When you have one layer that downloads a large temporary file and you delete it in another layer, that has the result of leaving the file in the first layer, where it gets sent over the network and stored on disk, even when it's not visible inside your container. Changing permissions on a file also results in the file being copied to the current layer with the new permissions, doubling the disk space and network bandwidth for that file.

The standard solution to reduce the image size in the above scenarios is to chain the `RUN` commands so that temporary files are never stored to an image layer. This has the side effect of reducing the number of image layers.

There's one last issue, which is excessive caching. This is commonly seen with the `apt-get update` and `apt-get install ...` commands in Debian images. If you do not chain these commands together, an update to the `apt-get install` command will reused a possibly stale cache from the previous layers `apt-get update` command, and will fail months later when it cannot find the needed packages. Therefore, you should chain these commands even though it will increase build time, because the other option is to have build failures in the future.

Therefore, it's more the side effects of reducing layers that you want, not necessarily reducing the layers for the sake of reducing layers.

Comment: How can chaining commands help avoid creating temp files? In most cases multiple step made to install different components in the image are independent, and chaining them will not help with reducing image size. If you are talking about building artifacts in a separate stage, I agree, but in most OS component configuration scenarios chaining will not have impact on size.

Comment: `curl; tar -xvf; ./install.sh; rm` is best done in one step rather than 4. Otherwise files created by curl and tar would be persisted in the layers. A step that is `RUN rm -rf $path` will slightly increase the image size.

Comment: Of course, if you explicitly clean up things with `rm`, and IF you have something to clean up. In many cases people chain independent steps that do not build one on top of another, which seems to have negligible effect on image size.

Comment: I think you might be implying something that I didn't say, but it's been over 6 years since I wrote it so I may be missing what you're referring to.

Comment: You answer is right for scenarios like download-unarchive-build-install-cleanup, but the original question was more generic as I understand it. Even today's Docker documentation contains questionable statements like "Combine commands together wherever possible" (https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/#combine-commands-together-wherever-possible), which will have zero positive effect on image size in case of independent commands/components. Note that I am not arguing with you, just trying to contribute to the answer, no need to defend.