# Multi-stage Docker: RUN wget vs ADD

Tags: docker

The [best practices section of the Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/) says this:

> Because image size matters, using ADD to fetch packages from remote
>   URLs is strongly discouraged; you should use curl or wget instead.
>   That way you can delete the files you no longer need after they’ve
>   been extracted and you won’t have to add another layer in your image.
>   For example, you should avoid doing things like:
>
> ```
> ADD http://example.com/big.tar.xz /usr/src/things/
> RUN tar -xJf /usr/src/things/big.tar.xz -C /usr/src/things
> RUN make -C /usr/src/things all
> ```
>
> And instead, do something like:
>
> ```
> RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/things \
>     && curl -SL http://example.com/big.tar.xz \
>     | tar -xJC /usr/src/things \
>     && make -C /usr/src/things all
> ```

On the other hand, later on it notes:

> Prior to Docker 17.05, and even more, prior to Docker 1.10, it was
>   important to minimize the number of layers in your image. [...] Docker
>   17.05 and higher add support for multi-stage builds, which allow you to copy only the artifacts you need into the final image.

and even

> compress[ing] two RUN commands together using the Bash && operator
>   [is] failure-prone and hard to maintain.

It seems to me that if you are using multi-stage builds, the advice about `ADD` is inaccurate. The extra layers are unlikely to be a problem unless you are downloading something truly huge, as *local* disk space is cheap and it's easy to clean out old images. Indeed, when coding one doesn't usually have build commands clean their intermediate artefacts to save space!

In addition, **`ADD` has a major advantage over `RUN wget`: it detects when its target has changed**.

Am I missing something, or do multi-stage builds rehabilitate `ADD`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does look like it: **[`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add)** is used for instance in the [Katakoda "Creating optimized Docker Images using Multi-Stage Builds"](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/docker/multi-stage-builds) example (for the *first* image, before the second stage.

With two steps, you can focus on minimizing the ([42-max for aufs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39383801/6309), [hard-limit 127](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1171#issuecomment-259692220)) layers in the second stage only.