# Share executable between docker images

Tags: docker, docker-volume

Maybe it is really lame question, but would it be possible to share some executables to all docker containers at once?

The reason is i.e. JDK part of the image is pretty big, why not put the binaries in some volume and then just execute java command from there?

Is it feasible at all or nonsense from the start?

Comment: Probably you're looking for `docker-compose`.

Comment: Are you generating that binary in the container or is it available on the host which you just want inside all the containers?

Comment: Let's talk for example specificaly about Java JVM or python, that will run the application inside the container. So JVM is probably even already available on the host.

Comment: It possible, but i'll prefer avoid this way. If you have a lot of images based on `jdk` docker smart enough to not download the same jdk many times.

Comment: But if you need to store the images it is really disk space hungry. Imagine container "version" per day. I know that nowadays the space is not so expesive, but still. Maybe it is about clearing the repository of unused images, but it is like purging old library versions from maven central.

Comment: have you take a look at this https://codefresh.io/blog/java_docker_pipeline/ ?

Comment: Actually I found that article hour ago, during research on my other question. What I try to resolve here is exactly what led me there. Back to my question, is it posible to base image on alpine linux and share the executables without adding additional JVM image layer?

Answer (score 1):

> The reason is i.e. JDK part of the image is pretty big, why not put the binaries in some volume and then just execute java command from there?

Docker images should be portable, and you should be able to start your image anywhere where Docker is installed. If you don't package all the dependencies inside the image, the image
will not be portable on any machine.

Comment: Is it possible ignoring the fact that it is not the docker way?

Comment: Yes it is possible and easy to do using a volume mount.