# Why does my Java process consumes twice memory inside a docker container vs host

Tags: java, docker, memory, heap-memory

I faced an interesting problem trying to analyze a memory consumption in my Java application running on docker container vs host machine.

1. The Java app is web app on the Jetty server 9.4.9
2. Java version : 1.8
3. Host : MAC
4. Docker images: jetty:9.4-jre8
5. The docker daemon is 18.03.1-ce version.

On the host I'm using Yourkit tool to analyze a memory consumption.

For docker container `docker stats <docker id/name>`

What I'm getting is that on MAC yourkit shows me 50M Non-heap size + ~40M heap size, in total ~**100M**

[image]

Whereas, when I deploy and run the same war on a container, the stats shows me **200M**

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
879fb113ca8d        jetty-app           0.19%               214.6MiB / 1.952GiB   10.74%              1.49MB / 88.9kB     31.7MB / 6.42MB     29
```

Can anyone shed some light on this phenomenon?

Assuming that `stats` provides wrong results, I tried to limit the memory on a container using `--memory` flag doesn't help much, I'm getting OOM.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Showing the exact output of `yourkit` and `docker stats` might be useful.

Comment: the output added

Comment: There are a couple of things here. 1. Note difference between MB and MiB. 2. `docker stats` might be including memory used by the threads stacks - this is by default 1MB per thread and is not included in heap memory or non-heap memory, so I would recommend checking thread count in yourkit. 3. Heap memory shown by yourkit looks a bit weird - although app is using only 25MB of heap memory, it might have more than that reserved (green line looks like 75MB).

Comment: The JVM itself can use 100 MB especially if you have native memory for things like Thread stacks, Sockets, buffers, JARs, the JVM shared libraries etc.

Comment: thanks guys for your tips, I will try to run the yourkit  on docker container instead of using docker stats command

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try and measure again, with an [openJDK 8u212](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8u-dev/2019-April/009115.html) or more (April, 16th 2019). (no Oracle JDK, since [their license has changed](https://java.com/en/download/release_notice.jsp))

See "[Docker support in Java 8 — finally!](https://blog.softwaremill.com/docker-support-in-new-java-8-finally-fd595df0ca54)" from [**Grzegorz Kocur**](https://blog.softwaremill.com/@grzegorz.kocur).
Now:

> There is no need to use any hacky workarounds in a docker entrypoint, nor setting Xmx as fixed value anymore.
>
> Docker support was also backported to Java 8.
>   Let’s check the newest openjdk image tagged as 8u212. We’ll limit the memory to 1G and use 1 CPU:
>
> ```
> docker run -ti --cpus 1 -m 1G openjdk:8u212-jdk
> ```

You can fine-tune the heap-size with new flags (already present in Java 10+, but now back ported to Java 8), and [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54297753/6309).

```
-XX:InitialRAMPercentage
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage
-XX:MinRAMPercentage
```

> If for some reason the new JVM behaviour is not desired it can be switched off using -`XX:-UseContainerSupport`.